# Is there any C++ function to sort a Hash table?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, hashtable

I want to know that how can I sort an unordered_map in C++ on the basis of its values (Not Keys, as the map can be used for that).
I understand that one solution is to copy its values to a vector and then sort that vector. But, Is there any function to do it?

Comment: well, you are storing things in an `unordered_` container, which does not require any comparison operator for its key type. If you really want to sort it, you have to do it somewhere else, or, maybe, use another container

Comment: You cannot *control* the location of elements in a [*UnorderedAssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer). 

You cannot *change* the location of elements in a [*AssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn’t a function but it’s a straightforward two-liner:

```
auto vec = std::vector<std::pair<TKey, TValue>>(begin(map), end(map));
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second < b.second; });
```